# KVM/QEMU No bootable device 0003 error and solution

Tags: qemu, kvm

I am new to kvm, so maybe a lot of you will take it silly, but I would like to describe the problem I had.
When I was typing

```
kvm
```

in qemu the error of 'no bootable device' with code 0003 occurs.

Comment: While it's acceptable to answer your own questions here, this is a "Question and Answer" site, which means  you can't post an answer until there has first been a question asked (which has to follow the same quality policies as any other question), at which point you can post an answer (again, which must adhere to the same quality requirements) in the space provided below for answers. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your command line is (implicitly) asking to create a virtual machine with no disk. The guest BIOS then looks for disks or CDROMs that it can boot from, and finds none. This is exactly the same behaviour as if you had a real hardware PC, and powered it up with no disks in it.

In general, the QEMU command line can be long and complicated, especially if you want best performance from the virtual machine. For most users it's often best to use a "management layer" program like libvirt, which takes care of these details for you, rather than trying to run QEMU directly.

Comment: You haven't posted a solution though, merely an explanation of the problem. Please expand with how to find the required diskspace. Thanks in advance

Comment: My suggested solution, targeted at users who think "just run kvm with no arguments" might work, is "use libvirt". I think that describing the QEMU command line option for "here is a disk image" is probably going to lead that category of user (who just wants "something that works", not "full manual control") down an unhelpful path where they will continue to run into further "I have no idea how to do this directly with QEMU" problems.

Comment: Accepted, but if every question on here elicits a working solution, anyone stumbling into whatever problem they face (and this one seems wuite common) can solve it and cross their fingers that the next sticking point they encounter will have an answer on here. "Use something else" is a tough answer.

Comment: It's exactly anybody who doesn't really know that QEMU is a very low level utility that I want to direct towards "strongly consider using the high-level interface instead"...

Comment: You  mean like kvm and its derivatives? virt-manager hits the same problem on my system.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix, which let me open the virtual machine through terminal was just to find it:

```
sudo find /var/lib/libvirt/images/
```

Choose the correct one and copy/paste the path to the code:

```
sudo kvm /var/lib/libvirt/images/Centos.qcow2
```

And thats it..
I couldn't find it in manual to qemu or kvm, but it is that easy, the hours of config changes and bus types were not necessary.